# How to get wbar with actual transparency?

Tags: lubuntu

I use Lubuntu 17.10 with the FLWM window manager. And I've installed this program called wbar, which is a dock for starting applications. 
But my problem is that the program is unusable for me, because it can only run under windows. Otherwise in the settings if you select "run above desktop" it will run above windows but it won't be transparent, it'll have an ugly rectangle around it with a bit of the desktop background behind it.
So how can I make it so that windows stay behind it but with actual transparency? Not just an ugly rectangle.

Comment: It may have no solution if the software hasn't been coded to account for your window manager specificities.

Comment: Well is there a solution for openbox?

Comment: If I knew of one I would answered already.